# How to serialize JSON to string without escape characters in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I would like to serialize a C# object to JSON in a string from .NET Core.

I have tried with this code, but it results in a string with escape characters for the quotes:

```
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sensorData);
```

This is the resulting string:

```
"{\"Id\":\"100201\",\"Timestamp\":\"2018-02-08T08:43:51.7189855Z\",\"Value\":12.3}"
```

How can I serialize the object into a string without the escape characters like this?

```
"{"Id":"100201","Timestamp":"2018-02-08T08:43:51.7189855Z","Value":12.3}"
```

Comment: it is like the later but in the debugger you would see escaping

Comment: No, it's not what I see in the debugger. The string really contains the escape characters.

Comment: where are you seeing the escape characters? i.e. if you do `File.WriteAllText(path, s);` - are the escape characters *in the file*? There's a good chance you're seeing this in the IDE and *incorrectly* thinking the characters are actually there.

Comment: Believe me, the backslashes are real.

Comment: @OlavT I'll believe you if you show a runnable example that actually shows it. I've just posted a runnable example that shows that they *aren't* there.

Comment: Ok, I will investigate more and come back with results.

Comment: You are right. There was no escape characters for real in the string. The escape characters where added by Event Grid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The escape characters *aren't there*. If we can reasonably assume that your `sensorData` is something like:

```
class SensorData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

then if I do:

```
var sensorData = new SensorData {
    Id = 100201,
    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
    Value = 12.3,
};
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sensorData);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

the output is:

```
{"Id":100201,"TimeStamp":"2018-02-08T10:30:40.2290218+00:00","Value":12.3}
```

The escape characters are an IDE feature, not part of the JSON. The IDE shows you strings *as you would need to copy and paste them in your target language*; so: if the value is the JSON posted above, then the IDE will *show* it as a C# literal:

```
"{\"Id\":100201, ...snip... , \"Value\":12.3}"
```

But: that isn't the *contents* of the string.

Comment: Adding to Marcs answer, if you were to return the serialized string from a controller in say WebAPI with something like `return Ok(s)`, you would also see the the escaped string with backslashes in the response and not the valid json.

Comment: The answer is correct. The escape characters wasn't there. The escape characters got added when I passed the string to Event Grid. What Visual Studio shows in the IDE is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc Gravell says, while debugging, use Json Viewer (Magnifier icon at the beginning or end of watch) and check.

If you are really getting escape characters as a part of Json response. Say while testing API using Postman or Fiddler, even in RAW response, try this:

ASP .NET core has data formatters and output is affected by **Accepts** header. If API is called with **Accepts**: **application/json** header, **try removing this header.**

Hope this is helpful for someone.